# What does "previous applicants need not apply" mean?

Tags: recruitment

Like it says in the title - on a job advert, does it usually mean that previous applicants will be automatically considered, or that they have already been considered and found unsuitable?

Comment: **It means you shouldn't apply.** There's no way to tell anything else as what you're asking about is specific to a company's internal workings (VTC).

Comment: I'm asking about in general, and not about a specific company. It's quite a common phrase and I imagine that there's an "understood" meaning behind it.

Comment: It does. The one I gave in bold. Absent a crystal ball you have no way to know what a particular company's meaning behind it is so an academic discussion of the "common" meanings is rather pointless and risks giving people the wrong idea.

Comment: @Eoin there is no "in general", only the person who specified that in the job advert knows what they mean.

Comment: @Eoin, you might find [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/95042/19446) on ELL useful

Answer (score 10):

It means - if you have applied in the past, please do not apply again.

Normally this would mean that as one was not found suitable in the past, the company believes they will not be found suitable in the present. They are trying to save time and effort.

It doesn't make much sense that previous (unsuccessful) applicants would be automatically considered - after all, they were unsuccessful (why do I say that? Well... if they got the job, they would have been successful).

Personally, I find this kind of phrasing to be short sighted - people change and learn. If one had acquired new skills or experience that would make them more suitable to this job at this time, they should be fine to apply again, regardless of this phrase.

Comment: Personally, I love seeing this.  I know not to even consider applying to such a short-sighted company